# ASP.NET MVC Model Binder returns null object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am having a problem where everytime I post a form back to the `[HttpPost]` version of my controller action, the ModelBinder returns a null object. I can't work out why. If I change the signature to use a `FormCollection` instead I can see that all the correct keys have been set. Can someone help me pin point what's wrong here, because I can't spot it.

Here are the models for working with my views

```
public class DeviceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "CodeName")]
    public string CodeName { get; set; }

    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceCreateViewModel : DeviceModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Manufacturers { get; set; } 
}
```

Which I use in my controller like so:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    DeviceCreateViewModel viewModel = new DeviceCreateViewModel()
                                            {
                                                Manufacturers = ManufacturerHelper.GetSortedManufacturersDropDownList()
                                            };

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DeviceModel model)
{
    // if I check model here it is NULL
    return View();
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
@model TMDM.Models.DeviceCreateViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManufacturerId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", Model.Manufacturers)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="medium green awesome" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Device", null, new { @class="medium black awesome" })
        </p>
    </fieldset> }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that there is a name collision between the property named `Model` in the class `DeviceModel` and the variable named `model` in the `Create` action.  The name collision causes the `DefaultModelBinder` to fail, since it tries to bind the Model property to the DeviceModel class.

Change the name of the variable in the Create action to `deviceModel` and it will bind correctly.

Comment: That worked thanks! But why does the name model work for another controller I have that accepts HttpPost data?

Comment: Does the model for that action also have a property named Model?  The reason it was failing here was because of the name collision.

Comment: OH sorry I actually misunderstood what you were saying before but I am clear now. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks for answer. It is not obvious, really.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in my case the parameter name was 'response' since I'm collecting R.S.V.P's - response is a sensible name and not a reserved word. It does the concern me the convention over configuration mantra seems to be overreaching in this case