# Sending array of inputs in form with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, forms

I have a store of products.
Each product has an Id, a price and a name.
When a person clicks on the "Buy" button, a form opens so they can fill up their address, their email and their name.
When the person clicks on submit, I do an AJAX call to the controller sending the information.

I have tried several solutions but I can't find one that works :/
What I want to do is send the email, address, name and an array of products.

carrinho.js (shoppingcart.js):

```
function go(nr) {
$('.confirm').toggleClass('comein');
$('#shoppingCart').toggle("fade");

var i = 0;

$("div #cartItems > .itemrow").each(function () {

    var nome = $(this).find("h3").text();
    var preco = $(this).find(".price").text();
    var id = $(this).find(".id").text();

    $("#form").append("" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='[" + i + "].produtos' value='" + nome + "' id='nomeenc' readonly /> " +
        "<input type='hidden' name='[" + i + "].produtos' value='" + id + "' id='idenc' readonly />" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='[" + i + "].produtos' value='" + preco + "' id='precoenc' readonly />");

    $(".messageSuccess button .removeItem").remove();
    $(".messageSuccess img").remove();
    i = i + 1;
});

$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Compra/Encomenda',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('.confirm').toggleClass('comein');
            $('#emptyCart').fadeToggle(nr);
            $('.messageSuccess').toggleClass('comein');
        }
    });
});
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Encomenda(SubmitFormModel produtos)
    {
        var model = produtos;

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/files");
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string date = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SubmitFormModel));
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path + "\\" + date + ".xml");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, model);
        writer.Close();

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

SubmitFormModel.cs:

```
namespace Loja.Models
{
[Serializable]
public class SubmitFormModel
{
public List<Produto> Produtos { get; set; } //produto = product
    public string Morada { get; set; } //address
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; } //name
}
```

}

Produto.cs:

```
namespace Loja.Models
{
[Serializable]
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome_produto { get; set; } //product_name
    public string Tipo { get; set; } //type
    public string Detalhes { get; set; } //details
    public string Imagem { get; set; } //image
    public int Preco { get; set; } //price
    public string ImgArt { get; set; }
}
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="/Compra/Encomenda" method="post" id="form">
    <label class="field a-field a-field_a3 page__field">
        <input class="field__input a-field__input" placeholder="ex. Rodrigo Barradinhas" required name="nome" type="text" id="nome_cliente">
        <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
            <span class="a-field__label">Nome completo</span>
        </span>
    </label>

    <label class="field a-field a-field_a3 page__field">
        <input class="field__input a-field__input" placeholder="ex. email@domain.com" required name="email" type="text" id="email">
        <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
            <span class="a-field__label">E-mail</span>
        </span>
    </label>

    <label class="field a-field a-field_a3 page__field">
        <input class="field__input a-field__input" placeholder="ex. Rua x Nºy 1167-004 Lisboa" required name="morada" type="text" id="morada">
        <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
            <span class="a-field__label">Morada</span>
        </span>
    </label>

    <input type='submit' name='confirmar' value='confirmar' class='event' data-main='Compra' />
    <br /><br />
</form>
```

I wanted to get in my controller something like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nJMv.jpg

and an array of products

Comment: Shouldn't it be `name='produtos[" + i + "].name'` instead of `name='[" + i + "].produtos'`? With one input per property like you do but with `name` equals to `produtos[" + i + "].**propertyName**`.

Comment: Also in the `each` method you're setting the same `id` to several `input` which is not a good idea as `ids` should be unique. I'd suggest you remove then if you don't need them.

Comment: @colinD About the ids, I have already remove them, that is from before, when I didn't had a foreach() and it was a single product

Comment: @colinD I tried what you suggested and this is what I get:
https://imgur.com/a/WRwmgwP

Comment: It should be `produtos[" + i + "].nome_produto` instead of `nome` to match the `Produto` model but other than that it's strange that the other properties aren't set anymore.

Comment: @colinD I understood what you mean and yes... very strange

Comment: Looks like it's a variable name problem that occurs during binding. Could you change the variable name in the method `public ActionResult Encomenda(SubmitFormModel produtos)` and see it if work? For example `Encomenda(SubmitFormModel formModel)`.

Comment: Not related to the original question but to the second problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509023

Comment: @colinD OMG that worked! Thank you so much. Got to be careful with var names :/
again, thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this. I always find dealing with JSON simpler than with multiple input attributes.

1. First of all I will recommend is instead of taking values from **text** of HTML, you should attach `**data-***` attributes. Let's say, your HTML is something similar to

```
<div id="cartItems">
    <div class="itemrow">
        ...
        <h3>Samsung Mobile S10</h3>
        <span class="price">350</span>
        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="34">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="itemrow">
        ...
        <h3>IPhone 7s</h3>
        <span class="price">650</span>
        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="38">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of this, you should create an HTML similar to this

```
<div id="cartItems">
    <div class="itemrow" data-pid="34" data-price="350" data-name="Samsung Mobile S10">
        ...
        <h3>Samsung Mobile S10</h3>
        <span class="price">350</span>
        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="34">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="itemrow" data-pid="38" data-price="650" data-name="IPhone 7s">
        ...
        <h3>IPhone 7s</h3>
        <span class="price">650</span>
        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="38">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

2. You should look to create a JSON array string of all the products in the cart. Create ONE hidden control and place your products JSON there.

```
<input type="hidden" id="allproductsjson" value="">
```

Your function can be similar to

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProductsJSON();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Compra/Encomenda',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('.confirm').toggleClass('comein');
            $('#emptyCart').fadeToggle(nr);
            $('.messageSuccess').toggleClass('comein');
        }
    });
});

function createProductsJSON() {
    var jsonObj = [];
    $("#cartItems > .itemrow").each(function() {
        var pId = $(this).attr("data-pid");
        var pName = $(this).attr("data-name);
        var pPrice = $(this).attr("data-price);

        var item = {}
        item ["id"] = pId;
        item ["name"] = pName;
        item ["price"] = pPrice;

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });

    console.log(jsonObj);
    $("#allproductsjson").val(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
}
```

3. In the controller, you will get just one field and you can simply do a parsejson to get the output.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello @Jay Pagnis, I apreciate your comment, thank you so much.
I will try this in a future project, but again, thank you very much!
I just finished 12 grade and im doing an internship in a company and I'm still learning :)
Hope to be a good programmer one day

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with var names :/

> Looks like it's a variable name problem that occurs during binding. Could you change the variable name in the method public ActionResult Encomenda(SubmitFormModel produtos) and see it if work? For example Encomenda(SubmitFormModel formModel). – colinD

It worked. Thank you